# How to find the turtle with the most neighbors in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

i am struggling with a way to find the turtle with the most neigbors in a radius of 3 and change its color. At the moment i tried something with a while loop that increases an the id of the turtles and tests if the number of neighbors is higher than the last one. But It's causing anf infinite loop and travels only between the id 0 and 1.

I can't seem to find where the error comes from, Here's the code i wrote:

```
to election  
  while [var1 < 9][
    ask turtle var1 [
      set voisin count turtles in-radius 3
      if voisin > maxi [
        set maxi voisin
        set idmax var1
      ]
      show voisin
      show idmax
      set var1 var1 + 1
      set color pink
    ]
  ]
  ask turtle idmax[
    set color green
  ]  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a single statement,

```
ask max-one-of turtles [count other turtles in-radius 3] [set color green]
```

`max-one-of` finds the turtle with the maximum value of the expression in brackets.  (If there are multiple turtles with that maximum value, then a random one of those with the maximum value is chosen.)  In the brackets, each turtle evaluates the number of other turtles in radius 3.  The `other` is not strictly necessary.  Without it, every turtle  will count itself, adding one to the count.